# ActionResult to same content

Tags: javascript, c#, html

Is it possible in MVC C# to return an ActionResult that does not modify the view at all?

I have tried:

Returning null and new EmptyResult(), but those return an empty page

Returning an empty JavaScript (again, empty page)

Returning a JavaScript that sets all the markup stored in a hidden field ("dangerous client markup" error).

What I am looking for is precisely the same page, including the current focus element, and preferably without a flicker refresh (textbox onkeyup calls a C# method that stores to database). If I cannot do this with an ActionResult, is there a way to call a non-ActionResult C# method that can access form elements in a JavaScript form? I am not using jQuery.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make action result return type as void or you can do this using ajax. Please check this [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1915594.aspx?Need%20MVC%20Actions%20that%20does%20not%20return%20any%20view)

Answer (score 0):

No, that not how browsers work - GET/POST request from page always replace whole page with server's response and browser never sends page information to server so it can re-render the same page.

Ways around:

- post enough information to your server to re-create the page (flicker is almost unavoidable)
- use AJAX request (JQuery or raw JavaScript) to post/get partial results and render with script
- use IFrame to post data and not touch the page.